# Is there a single player PC game with similar mechanics to Twilight Imperium?

Tags: twilight-imperium

I recently started playing Twilight Imperium, and it's a blast. I really like the political aspect, technology aspect, and the mobilization of fleets. I really wish there was a PC game similar to this. I've been playing Civilization since Civ1 through Civ3, and that series is the closest PC game I can think of; however, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I like how the production in TI is based on resources instead of production of a city. I also like how the politic cards change the rules as the game progresses. Does any one know of a PC game that has similar mechanics?

Comment: Hey Dave!  Sorry I had to close your question.  This site is for discussing Boardgames, not computer games.  Also, we restrict questions asking for recommendations as they are highly subjective.

Comment: Hey Pat, No problem. I thought it may be off topic, but I thought more people on this site would have heard of TI than on the video game site. I got an answer, and I'm happy with that. Thanks.

Comment: Spaceward Ho! is kind of similar but not as in depth. It's also got a fog of war aspect to it that Twilight imperium doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The Master's of Orion series is probably the closest PC game to Twilight Imperium, and a great game as well.

Other people seem to think [this as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4X), [see here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/63217/master-of-orion), or [here](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?479026-Twilight-Imperium-Master-of-Orion-the-boardgame).

You could also go full circle, and say that TI ispired the [Masters of Orion boardgame](http://moo3.quicksilver.com/diary/1200.html).